# Xamarin Image from Url not showing

Tags: xamarin.android

I'm trying to show this image in my Xamarin.forms application:
https://i.ibb.co/NZLyXK1/kuhstall.png

This is the xaml code:

```
<Image Source="https://i.ibb.co/NZLyXK1/kuhstall.png" HeightRequest="60" WidthRequest="60" Aspect="AspectFill" BackgroundColor="#487F40"/>
```

I'm currently testing this on an Android device, and there is no image showing, only the background color.

I have tried the following settings in Android Settings Advanced:

HttpClient Implementation: **Android**
SSL/TSL Implementation: **Native TLS 1.2+**

and

HttpClient Implementation: **Managed**
SSL/TSL Implementation: **Native TLS 1.2+**

I have also tried removing the "s" from "https" but without luck.

Does somebody know a fix for this?

Comment: There is an issue in Xamarin.forms version 4.2.0.778463 early.So the solution is update your Xamarin.forms version to the latest 4.2.0.848062.

**Note:**  After updating the Xamarin.forms version, you have to just uninstall the app and delete the obj/bin folder both under Xamrin.forms project and Xamarin.Android project. Then clean and rebuild again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, what fixed my issue was implementing ***FFImageLoading*** and using a ***CachedImage*** instead a regular image. Also the HttpClient Implementation in adavanced settings was set to **Android**. Don't know if that has anything to do with it.

Comment: Don't forget to accept your answer , which will help more people .